# How to access a variable in inherited class based views

Tags: django, django-views

I am wondering how to run a reality check to decide which template file to use. How do I access agency_count from AgencyFullView? What I currently have returns **type object 'AgencyFullMixin' has no attribute 'agency_count'**

```
class AgencyFullMixin(ContextMixin):

    def get_context_data(self, pk, **kwargs):
        context_data = super(AgencyFullMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        agency = Agencies.objects.filter(pk=pk)
        context_data["agency"] = agency
        agency_count = agency.count()
        context_data["agency_count"] = agency_count
        return context_data

class AgencyFullView(TemplateView, AgencyFullMixin):

    if agency_count != 0:    **<<<--- What to put here?**
        template_name = 'community_information_database/agency_full.html'
    else: 
        template_name = 'community_information_database/not_valid.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context_data = super(AgencyFullView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context_data
```

Comment: The code in AgencyFullView seems to be written right in the body of the class. Is that really the case? Also, there seems to be no `agency_count` variable in the mixin class either, you have `agency_count_test`. Mind you that `agency_count_test` is a local variable and it will go away once the get_context_data() method returns.

Comment: You are trying to set your template at the class level based on something that will only be calculated on request. This is not going to work. Your `if agency_count != 0` code will only run once at the application start, not for every request and so cannot use this count.

Comment: @Mad Wombat    I have removed the  _test typo

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, instead of adding it to your question. The code you have posted doesn't make sense -- you shouldn't have `return` outside of a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Fixed: Here's the solution I am using:

```
class AgencyFullMixin(ContextMixin):

    def get_context_data(self, pk, **kwargs):
        context_data = super(AgencyFullMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        agency = Agencies.objects.filter(pk=pk)
        context_data["agency"] = agency
        agency_count = agency.count()
        context_data["agency_count"] = agency_count
        return context_data

class AgencyFullView(TemplateView, AgencyFullMixin):
    def get_template_names(self, **kwargs):
        agency = Agencies.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs['pk']).filter(pk__isnull=False)
        if agency:
            return 'community_information_database/agency_full.html'
        else:
            return 'community_information_database/not_valid.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context_data = super(AgencyFullView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context_data
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to access `agency_count` in another method, then you'll have to set it as an attribute. You could do this in the dispatch method.

```
class AgencyFullMixin(ContextMixin):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        agencies = Agencies.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        self.agency_count = agencies.count()
        return super(AgencyFullMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """
        Add the agency count to the context
        """
        context = super(AgencyFullMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['agency_count'] = self.agency_count
        return context
```

You can then access `self.agency_count` in other methods. To change the template name dynamically, you should override `get_template_names`.

```
class AgencyFullView(AgencyFullMixin, TemplateView):
    def get_template_names(self):
        if self.agency_count != 0:
            template = 'community_information_database/agency_full.html'
        else: 
            template = 'community_information_database/not_valid.html'
        return [template]  # nb get_template_names must return a list
```

Comment: I get the following error:   'super' object has no attribute 'get'.

This line is throwing the error:
    return super(AgencyFullMixin, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

Comment: Try changing the order of your classes.